# How to provide thread-safe access to elements of a large array

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++17

I have a very large (tens of gigabytes) mmap'd array of doubles in memory that I need to provide thread-safe access to. The access pattern is frequent reads with occasional writes (additions). There are only a few dozen threads, so the chance of collision is low, but not zero.

Things I have considered:

- I could create one mutex per element, but that seems wasteful in terms of memory.
- I could create a unordered_set that stores the elements being written to. This isn't horrible if it's a shared lock, but inserting and deleting each time I write a double seems heavy in terms of run-time overhead

I'm wondering if there's a way to do something similar to `fetch_add` without making all the doubles atomic (especially since `atomic<double>` mostly isn't implemented in C++ until C++20).

Is there a better way to provide this kind of thread-safe access?

Comment: Perhaps one `std::shared_mutex` for every N elements?  Benchmarking different values of N might reveal one that works well. It wouldn't be "perfect" (an exclusive lock would block access to elements that aren't in use) but often the goal when dealing with scalability isn't "perfect" but "good enough."

Comment: Does the order of operations matter? What kind of updates does the writing thread perform? Does the reading thread require the consistency of data and any invariants hold?

Comment: What do you mean by "`atomic<double>` not implemented"? Even if the `fetch_add` is not implemented you can always use a compare-and-swap operation.

Comment: The writing thread just does additions. I'm not sure how to use `atomic<double>` given that the array is mmap'd

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is said about the consistency of data in your question, and that is the most important aspect. I'll try to describe several possible patterns, maybe one of them would satisfy the needs of your project.

First, let's imagine that there may be no consistency between the doubles in your huge mmap: something like sensors data that doesn't require consistency between sensors. You may use `atomic<double>` with the `atomic::store` operation: you just store and read some data, and the only consistency is that each element has either new or old value (the atomic guarantees just that the double is consistent). If you need the `fetch_add` operation, you may always implement it by yourself using a `compare_exchange_weak`.

Next case: there should be some consistency in records. You need to define what the record is and have a `shared_mutex` (or any other lock) on per-record basis.

One more option: let's say you need a consistency between records but you don't need them to be fully synchronized. Something like cached data, where this data is eventually updated (relaxed memory model in C++). You may have a `shared_ptr` to the actual data. Each reading thread can copy the shared pointer and get the ownership of the data to read (that is a cheap operation, and C++ guarantees thread safety). Once the data is read the thread has to destroy it's copy of the shared pointer and release the ownership. The interesting part is the writing thread. It creates a copy of data into a "swap" memory and this memory is being owned by an independent shared pointer. The writing thread updates the data, and it may take as much time as it needs: the reading threads do not know that there exists a "swap" and still use the old data. Once the writing thread finishes it's job it stores the `shared_ptr` to swap memory into the actual data shared pointer.

What is important: at the time the writing thread commits it's job there still may be reading threads using old data. That is not a problem - they have the ownership on old data, and this data is just slightly outdated. New readers would get updated data anyway.

Comment: Syntactically, I'm not sure how to use `atomic<double>` in conjunction with the mmap. The shared_ptr approach is very interesting though

Comment: If you have a pointer to the memory, you may use *placement new* operator to place any type of objects there. You may create an array of atomic values using placement new.